# Json doesn't install on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I took a look to a lot of errors like this but no solution one works for me. I had Rails working till some days ago, and i can't really understand what's wrong with it. Making a bundle install of a new app, it gives:

```
Installing json (1.7.7) with native extensions
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
generating generator-i386-mingw32.def
make: *** [generator-i386-mingw32.def] Error 253


Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
/gems/json-1.7.7 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.7/
ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing json (1.7.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.7.7'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I have the DevKit installed, after have reinstalled everything with the RailsInstaller, then installed DevKit by itself. I have MinGW installed.

I am not new to Rails, I can't just figure out what's wrong, some days ago everything was working.. and I can't think to something I've installed that can make conflicts

Thanks.

EDIT with Solution: I finally got it working (some days after posted this) by reinstalling the operating system :)
Then I understood trying it another time and swearing against the command line, the fault was of ansicon, making crashing every single executable via command line and via windows services. Every recent version I tried makes this, I can't explain it.

Comment: Thanks for the EDIT part! ansicon does mess up my rails command and cygwin (even rm malfunction!) under windows, and cause creation of rails project halt at the json gem part. Removing ansicon does solve the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this troubleshooting guide at Rubyinstaller wiki: https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Troubleshooting#wiki-gems_fails_comspec_autorun

My case was after updating Windows and "Scenario B" do the "trick".

Comment: "Scenario B" also corrected it for me. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue and tried with

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
platforms :ruby do
  gem 'json'
end

platforms :mswin, :mingw do
  gem 'json_pure'
end
```

in gem file and I got it working